# Distribute points on grid geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to do something like on picture windows are distributed on face height and length also on angled faces. Any ideas ???

[image]

Update: Is it possible to convert it to 3d space

[image]

Comment: I think @vklidu actually answered your question well, and his technique works well with a grid. What you want to do with your update is a completely different question, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree probably better to ask a new question ... I wanted to offer "array" grid in Z axis and use "Mesh Boolean" node, that works kind of, but it generates extra vertices. https://imgur.com/Dw4S0qO ... And Boolean grid as vertices doesn't work at all. Hmm

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this in 3D? I'm trying to select points by proximity to the face of another geometry node primitive and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is kind of working ...

- *Plane* object as base mesh
- *Grid* primitive node for points distribution in larger area
- All points inside the *Plane* are taken by **Geometry Proximity** node > *Face* as *Selection* factor for Instancing.

[image]
[image]

---

Tip: With this math you can easily extend grid by single value (integer) in meters ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: If for some reason scaling was not enough, could you do some attribute trickery where all instances not in proximity don't get an attribute applied, and then you do some sort of selection where only the ones with the attribute are kept?

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure I understand ... have you noticed my note under node tree? You can use Proximity for Selection (instead of Scale).

Comment: I had in fact missed that note.  Thanks.  Still get tripped up by geometry nodes letting you plug all manner of things into an equally varied number of socket types.

Comment: Why do you scale them? You have selection input to filter them out

Comment: Is it possible to make it in 3d geometry ???

Comment: @Cranitz ... I didn't want to cross the wires :) Selection is mentioned in sentence bellow the screen ... I will change the screen :)

Answer (score 2):

Version based on **Curve** ...

- one curve in X axis > *Curve to Points*
- on these points instance second curve in Y axis already with *Curve to Points*
- you just control **End Points** of those curves

[image]
[image]

[image]